# ACI deployment issue

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I’m unable to deploy machine learning models using ACI.

```
service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                       name=service_name,
                       models=[word2vec_model],
                       inference_config=inf_config,
                       deployment_config=aci_config)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Can you please suggest how can I debug the problem?

Comment: what version of the SDK? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Azure Machine Learning SDK  v1.0.85.

Comment: still need the error message

Answer (score 0):

Typically run into a variety of issues usually when uploading or downloading… Here are details on single node AKS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service#create-a-new-aks-cluster

“User Errors” for image build failures, I’m assuming this is when you’re intentionally attempting to break it with messed up dependencies. And “Timeouts” where we are unable to talk to the ACI container which could very well be because of the size of the model.